# Insert values into table based on condition, sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I try to insert values into my table in stored procedure based on the conditions:

```
alter procedure service_report_st2
as
insert into Service_report_step1(appointment_or_house) 
select
case
when Service_report_step1.card_uid in(select card_uid from visits where vidpos_kod = 'A')
then '1'

when Service_report_step1.card_uid in(select card_uid from visits  where vidpos_kod = 'B')
then '2'

else '3'
end
```

The error is in `Service_report_step1.card_uid` it is not found, however this is the first column in `Service_report_step1` table. `appointment_or_house` is the second column, which should contain '1', '2' or '3' if `visits` table contains `card_uid` in `Service_report_step1`.

I'd appreciate any help!

Short example:

`Visits` table has 2 columns: Card_uid and vidpos_kod

```
card_uid         vidpos_kod
 111-111              A
 222-222              B
 333-333              A
 444-444              C
```

now `Service_report_step1` table has card_uid (column that contains all possible cards) and appointment_or_house column

```
card_uid      appointment_or_house
 111-111              1
 222-222              2
 333-333              1
 444-444              1
```

So, If I have the same `card_uids` in `Service_report_step1` as in `Visits` I determine `appointment_or_house` column based on `vidpos_kod` in `Visits` (`A, C` is '1', `B` is '2')

I need to insert into `Service_report_step1` all data correctly as in example.

Comment: Your `SELECT` is lacking a `FROM` clause that defines which table you're selecting your rows from .....

Answer (score 2):

You are using a select statement, but without a `FROM clause`

You need to specify

```
INSERT INTO ...
SELECT *
FROM ...
```

Or something like that.

The other option would be to use [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into Service_report_step1(appointment_or_house) 
select
case vidpos_kod
when 'A' then '1'
when 'B' then '2'
when 'C' then '3'
end
from visits 
where vidpos_kod like '[ABC]'
```