# Inserting sql with conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, insert, case-when

I tried to apply the tips given in this post [Insert values into table based on condition, sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18118489/insert-values-into-table-based-on-condition-sql-server) to  make a conditional insert that depending on 3 different values of an attribute, assigns another attribute from the same table a number. This was my approach:

```
insert into tablerel (section, number) 
select
case section
when 'Paris' then tablerel.numseq=0
when 'NY' then tablerel.numseq=1
when 'Tokio' then tablerel.numseq=3
end
from tabledata 
;
```

PS: section is a varchar(5) and numseq a number(1), the reason to use it is for making faster searchs

Comment: Good. Next time, also try to put a question in there, along with some errors you got or other relevant description of the problem. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the right number of columns. In this particular case, I think you need to select `section` itself as well as a separate column:

```
insert into tablerel (section, number) 
select
  section, /* <-- This one */
  case section
  when 'Paris' then '0'
  when 'NY' then '1'
  when 'Tokio' then '3'
  end
from tabledata;
```

Comment: `tablere1` references in the `case .. when` won't work. They should probably me just `'0'`, `'1'` and `'3'` (can't be sure as the OP used `numseq` here while using `number` in the listed fields for insert, so this could be different fields). But then again as you noted in your comment to the question, the OP's problem is not clear :/

Comment: What do you mean with OP and what didnt i let it clear?

Comment: OP = original poster = TS = topic starter = you. :) The thing that isn't clear, is what your actual problem is. You just told a story about how you were doing something. No problem description, no error message. The reason I knew something was wrong, was because you posted it on SO, otherwise it could just as well have been an anekdote. :)

Comment: @Gorkk I overlooked the use of `tablerel` in the select statement, but I think you're right. I've updated the statement.